# Initial state from component to store with server side rendering

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reactjs.net

Application A will post data to application B which will be the initial state for Application B. To do this I am making use of Reactjs.Net

Application B will receive initial data as Post data from Application A. I need to set this post data as initialState in my store. To do this I am making use of Reactjs.net.

I read the post data in the controller, map the data to my object and assign it to viewbag to make it available in my view.

Below is what my view looks like. I read the InitialData from ViewBag and assign it so that it can be accessed in my React component.

```
@Styles.Render("~/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts")

@Html.React("InitialData", new { LoadData = ViewBag.InitialDataObject })

<script src="/react-15.0.1.js"></script>
<script src="/react-dom-15.0.1.js"></script>

<div class="container  pad-l-0px pad-r-0px">
    <div id="app"></div>
</div>

<script src="~/public/bundle.js"></script>
```

In the React component, I am able to get the data. Now how do I pass this data to the store as initialState and what is the best way?

```
var InitialData = React.createClass({   
    getInitialState: function () {
        return { InitialLoadData: this.props.LoadData };
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
          <div></div>
     );
    }
});
```

I will be using Server-side rendering only to set the initial state. I know I can assign the data to a global variable in my view and direct access that variable in my reducer. But I want to avoid doing that.

Comment: You shouldn't be making an AJAX call for your initial state. The initial state should either be the information needed by the app without any user input, or the barebones data structure needed for the view to render. Make your network call in `componentDidMount`, and then update the state with `this.setState()` after the call completes.

Comment: I am not making an AJAX call. Initial state comes as post so I am using server side rendering to make pass on the post data to redux store.

Answer (score 2):

If youre using Redux, you dont supply initial store data from a component, but you supply it as a parameter for `createStore`.

What you would typically do is assign your initial state to a script variable in the serverside output, and use that variable when you initialize your store.

See this page for a detailed example:
http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html

Comment: I am trying to follow http://reactjs.net/guides/server-side-rendering.html. I have the data in the component which I am trying to pass to createstore as a parameter.